# Need a car-friendly way to listen to music?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, lock-screens, music-player

Here is specifically what I'm looking for.

1)  I would like the ability to use gesture/swipe controls to skip tracks.  This is much easier than finding a button on a touchscreen to change tracks.

2)  Ability to either prevent a lockscreen or control the player from the lockscreen.  I don't mind if I have to push the power button to get the screen to wakeup, but once I do, I would like the ability to control the music player without going through the Android screen lock.  I see this accomplished through either a certain type of music app, or some application that allows me to control what applications prevent a screen from locking.

I have a rooted Samsung Captivate (Galaxy-S) running a custom ROM variant of 2.2.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go download [PowerAmp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&feature=search_result).  Best $5 I ever spent on an app.

It includes lockscreen controls and I'm pretty sure you can set up lockscreen gestures to do whatever you want.  I'll confirm this real quick on my installation.

**Edit:** Confirmed on the lockscreen gestures.  Swiping left and right over the album art will skip the track forward and backward by default, from anywhere in the app or on the lockscreen.

Comment: Does it allow me to send audio to my parrot bluetooth head unit? I'd LOVE that.

Comment: @Pitto - I dunno, I don't use a BT headset so I've obviously never tried it.  As Chance said in his comment they offer a 15-day free trial, so you've really got nothing to lose by giving it a shot.

Comment: I'll get my lazy *** off this chair and do it :D Thanks!

Comment: I'm using it right now.  Great app.  Have you found a way to pause it other than the pause button or removing the headphones?  I want to be able to pause it without looking for the button on the screen.